# Mostrar contenido de un archivo XML en HTML

Tags: html, python, ajax, xml

Quiero mostrar el contenido del archivo XML que selecciono en el formulario con un input, pero no me funciona.

He probado distintas formas y no doy con la tecla; he probado a que me devuelta el nombre del archivo después de ser elegido y si funciona, pero el contenido no lo consigo.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<form method="GET" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="archivo"/><br />
    <input type="submit" onclick="loadDoc()" value="Visualizar archivo">
</form>

<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>

function loadDoc()
{

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for old IE browsers
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {

            if(this.responseXML !== null){

                myFuncion(this);    
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","archivo", true);
    xhttp.send();
}


function myFuncion(xml)
{
    //guardo el contenido del archivo en xmlDoc
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

    //declaro una tabla para mostrar los datos
    var table = "<tr><th>Titulo</th><th>Autor</th></tr>";
    //guardo en la variable X los valores que se encuentren con el Tag Book para recorrer el fichero xml
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");

        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 

            table += "<tr><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td></tr>";
        }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}

</script>
```

El archivo XML que tengo es este:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tabla.xsl">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="COOKING">
   <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
   <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
   <year>2005</year>
   <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="CHILDREN">
   <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
   <author>J K. Rowling</author>
   <year>2005</year>
   <price>29.99</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta python?

Comment: jquery es tu amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo un submit innecesario y carente de funcionalidad. Lo único que tienes que hacer es:

1. Cargar el archivo XML en memoria.
2. Leer el archivo.
3. Parsear el contenido del archivo a un `document`.
4. Extraer la data del nuevo documento.

Para leer el archivo simplemente basta con crear una instancia de `FileReader` y usar el método `readAsText` pasándole como parámetro el `Blob` que representa el archivo seleccionado.

Para parsear el archivo solo necesitamos instanciar `DOMParser` y usar el método `parseFromString` al cual le pasamos dos parámetros: el texto plano y su mime type correspondiente.

**Ejemplo completo**

```js
function loadDoc(e) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];

  if (!file) {
    throw new Error('You need to choose an XML file first')
    alert('You need to choose an XML file first')
    return false
  }

  readDoc(file).then(parseDoc).then(showDocInTable).catch(onError)
}

function readDoc(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader()

  return new Promise((ok) => {
    reader.readAsText(file)
    reader.onload = function() {
      ok(reader.result)
    }
  })
}

function parseDoc(rawXML) {
  const parser = new DOMParser()
  const xml = parser.parseFromString(rawXML, 'text/html')
  return xml
}

function showDocInTable(xml) {
  const table = document.querySelector('#bookTable > tbody')
  const datasource = xml.querySelector('bookstore')
  const books = datasource.querySelectorAll('book')

  table.removeChild(table.children[0])

  Array.from(books).map((book, i) => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    const title = tagToData(book.querySelector('title'))
    const author = tagToData(book.querySelector('author'))
    const year = tagToData(book.querySelector('year'))
    const price = tagToData(book.querySelector('price'))

    tr.append(title, author, year, price)
    table.appendChild(tr)
  })
}

function tagToData(tag) {
  const td = document.createElement('td')
  td.textContent = tag.textContent
  return td
}

function onError(reason) {
  console.error(reason)
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, arial;
  padding: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
  grid-gap: 0 20px;
}

#bookForm {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

#bookForm input {
  display: none;
}

#bookForm label {
  background-color: #00AF3F;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#bookTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#bookTable td,
#bookTable th {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

#bookTable thead {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

#bookTable thead th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#bookTable tbody {
  padding: 10px;
}

#bookTable tbody tr:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

#bookTable tbody td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="bookForm">
  <input id="books" type="file" onChange="loadDoc(event)">
  <label for="books">Cargar archivo</label>
</div>

<table id="bookTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Autor</th>
      <th>Título</th>
      <th>Año</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center">Sin registros</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!

¿Como puedo cargar el archivo en memoria?, he puesto:
    <input type="file" name="archivo">

para hacer la selección del archivo, pero aun así no me funciona. El codigo que me has escrito funciona de maravilla y es el funcionamiento que deseo.
¿Es necesario tener el form ? 

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Vale! ya he conseguido que me funcione, tuve un pequeño despiste.

Mil Gracias de nuevo.